# How to get the text of li without giving them ids?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have four `li` tags inside a `ul` tag.

i want to get text inside li tag when i select one li and i want to hide the other three li values.

Only the selected one should still be shown on the page.

```
<ul id="names">
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
  <li>d</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#names li').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**This answers both parts of your question:**

```
$('#names li').click(function(){    
  var x = $(this).text(); // gets the text of the selected li
  alert(x); // displays the text inside the selected li 
  $(this).siblings().hide();​​​​ // hides all other li's   
});
```

Here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FTUQF/) for your example.

Comment: .val() wont get the text. I think it should be `.text()` as shown above answers.

Comment: @MayuMayooresan Changed. My answer seems to be the only one answering the whole question.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? It will hide them all and display the one which was clicked using a jQuery selector.

```
$('#names li').click(function() {
    $('#names li').hide();
    $(this).show();
})
```

Example of use: http://jsfiddle.net/eqUD3/

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$("#names li").click(function(){
   var selected = $(this);
   alert('You have selected '+ $(this).text());
   $("#names li").hide();
   $(this).show();
});
```

check the fiddle [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/eqUD3/3/)

Comment: That _if_ condition will always be true, because _$(this)_ will always return a new object which will never be equal to the object that _selected_ refers to...